# Problems in understanding javascript nested for loops

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

I try to understand **nested for loops** in **javascript** but it's very confusing.

I have this code and I can't understand how it works:

```
let n = 5;
for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    console.log(j);
}}
```

In console I have : 0
1
0
1
2
0
1
2
3

And I'm trying to figure out which loop represent each number.

Comment: Tip: Run the program yourself using only a pen and paper.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173)

Comment: A loop doesn’t “represent” a number. Do you know how a simple loop works, exactly? Read the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for). A loop executes statements as long as a condition holds. A loop is itself a statement.

Comment: Include `i` in the log also and it will probably help you visualize better

Comment: Tip: `console.log({ i, j });`.

Comment: BTW: The output is NOT "0 1 0 1 2 0 1 2 3", take a look at your console output, there should be a small number (2) left beside your first 0. It tells you that you have the first 0 two times. The output is "0 0 1 0 1 2 0 1 2 3"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this code:

```js
let n = 5;
let str = '';
for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < i; j++)
        str += j;
   
   console.log("Outer: "+i+" Inner: "+str);
   str = '';
}
```

Output is:

```
Outer: 0 Inner: 
Outer: 1 Inner: 0
Outer: 2 Inner: 01
Outer: 3 Inner: 012
Outer: 4 Inner: 0123
```

As you can see, in the output above, inner loop (the one with variable `j`) doesn't run, because if you replace the variables with numbers it would be
`0 < 0` (i < 0), which isn't true.

The best way for you to understand how nested loops work is to write each step and variable values on the paper, like so:

n = 5

STEP 1:

- i = 0
- i < n (0 < 5) TRUE

  - j = 0
  - j < i (0 < 0) FALSE inner loop doesn't execute
- OUTPUT: `"Outer: 0 Inner:"`
- str = ''

STEP 2:

- i = 1
- i < n (1 < 5) TRUE

  - j = 0
  - j < i (0 < 1) TRUE
  - str = 0
  - j = 1 (j++)
  - j < i (1 < 1) FALSE
- OUTPUT: `"Outer: 1 Inner: 0"`
- str = ''

And so on... Keep repeating this until the argument in the outer loop is false (i < n).

You must remember, in for loop the sequence of orders executed:

```
for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  console.log('It works');
}
```

1. let i = 0; (this executes only once)
2. i < 5 (if true run 3 and 4)
3. run the code in loop
4. i ++
5. i < 5 (if true run 6 and 7)
6. run the code in loop
7. i++

etc.

Comment: Thank you so much! You explained better than many tutorials I found

Comment: No problem, I'm glad i could help you out :)